# Python class instance __dict__ doesn't contain all instance variables. Why?

Tags: python, class, python-2.7

Here's a bit of a newbie Python question about instance variables.

Consider the following Python 2.7 class definition:

```
class Foo(object):
    a = 1

    def __init__(self):
            self.b = 2

    def __repr__(self):
            return "%s" % self.__dict__
```

Now, when I create an instance of `Foo`, `Foo.__dict__` contains `b`, but not `a`.

```
>>> x=Foo()
>>> x
{'b': 2}
>>> dir(x)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', 
 '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', 
 '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__',
 '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'a', 'b']
>>> x.__dict__
{'b': 2}
```

And here I thought I had a pretty good grasp on the Way of the Python.

What's the difference between `x.a` and `x.b`?  As far as I can tell they're both instance variables.

**Edit**: OK, re-reading the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects) I see that `Foo.a` is a *class attribute* rather than an instance variable.  Hm... I guess the confusion comes from the fact that I can assign a new value to `x.a` and the new value only affects the `x` instance -- I suppose I'm now aliasing a member variable over the top of the `Foo.a` attribute:

```
>>> y=Foo()
>>> y.a = 2
>>> y
{'a': 2, 'b': 2}
>>> x
{'b': 2}
>>> x.a
1
>>> z=Foo()
>>> z
{'b': 2}
>>> z.a
1
>>> Foo.a
1
>>> x.a
1
>>> y.a
2
```

So, now I overwrite the previous value of `Foo.a`, and it affects all instances of `Foo` that haven't aliased `Foo.a`:

```
>>> Foo.a=999
>>> x.a
999
>>> y.a
2
```

Comment: Note also that it's not good practice to rely on `__dict__` too much: clases using `__slots__` and extension classes (from C or Cython) don't put everything in there either. Most uses can be replaced by some combination of `getattr`, `setattr`, `hasattr`, and `dir`.

Comment: @Dougal: Thanks for that advice -- I saw that on another answer here on StackOverflow, but it's good reinforcement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `a` isn't an instance variable. You defined it as part of the class.

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...    a = 1
...
>>> Foo.a
1
```

If you want an instance variable you should put it inside the `__init__` method, because this method is called when your object is created.

Answer (score 4):

`a` is not an instance attribute, it's a class attribute.

Comment: Yes, but if I assign a new value to `x.a` it affects only the `x` instance.  If it's a class attribute, why doesn't changing the value of `x.a` affect all instances of `Foo`?

Comment: Because you assigned it on the instance.

Comment: Yes, I see that now.  I missed that on my initial read of the docs.  Thanks for the assist!

Answer (score 0):

May this help you further?

```
>>> class X(object):

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        print name
        return object.__getattribute__(self, name)


>>> l = dir(X())
__dict__
__members__
__methods__
__class__
>>> l
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__']
```